# .NET MVC - Routing POST and GET to the same controller, but different methods

Tags: rest, post, methods, get, .net

I have this route configuration in RouteConfig.cs:

```
// notes for a receipt
routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Get Notes for a receipt",
        routeTemplate: "receipt/{ReceiptID}/notes",
        defaults: new { 
                controller = "Receipt",
                action = "GetNotes",
                ReceiptID = RouteParameter.Optional
        }
);
```

All GET requests to a matching URL are routed to this method:

```
/// <summary>
/// retrieve notes for a receipt
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ReceiptID">receipt guid</param>
/// <returns>list of notes</returns>
[HttpGet]
public List<NoteDTO> GetNotes(Guid ReceiptID)
{
        try
        {
                IEnumerable<tNotes> Notes = Retriever.GetNotes(ReceiptID);
                return ObjectMapper.MapNotes(Notes);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
                // TODO more granular error handling
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }
}
```

This works fine. I would however like to be able to send a POST request to the exact same URL, but then calling a different method. However I receive a 405 Method Not Allowed: "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."

I have added the [HttpPost] Annotation to the method I want to be called but I'm missing a way to add the Http Request Type to the Routing Config.

I think I'm looking for something like this:

```
defaults: new { 
    controller = "Receipt",
    httpMethod = "POST, // specify http method 
    action = "GetNotes",
    ReceiptID = RouteParameter.Optional
}
```

Comment: Your method is defined with the attribute `HttpGet` therefore it will not accept `POST` as a valid HTTP method.  You could either make a new method with the attribute `HttpPost` or see if the current method can accept both attributes on the same method.

Comment: I don't want to route a POST Request to the same method, I only want to use the same URL for two different methods.
Which method is called should depend on the HTTP Request Type, so GET /user/ should call LookupUser(), POST /user/ should call UpdateUser()